# Writing A manual pop function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Before I get started :

```
import sys
sys.ps1 = "<?>> "
```

OK.
Being a C programmer at heart, I can't help but stay sharp in any way (in any language of my choosing) but by writing low level procedures. Today a question arose from a very simple example in Python3.

When writing a little pop() into a Stack class I received some curious output.

```
class Stack():

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.stack = [i for i in data]
        self.size = int(len(self.stack))

    def pop(self):
        ch = self.stack[self.size - 1]
        del(self.stack[-1])
        self.size = self.size - 1
        return ch


msg = Stack("Hello!")
for i in msg.stack:
    print(m.pop(), end="")

<?>> !ol

for i in msg.stack:
    print(m.pop(), end="")

<?>> le

for i in msg.stack:
    print(m.pop(), end="")

<?>> H

print(msg.stack)

<?>> []
```

As you can see 3 loops are required to pop and output the entire list ['H','e','l','l','o']; 3 chars, then 2, then 1, but the list depletes accordingly? More loops are required for longer input. What is the inhibitory factor at play here?

Comment: It works without needing 3 loops if I use `for i in range(len(msg.stack))` but that makes me all the more curious as to why it doesn't work accordingly without doing so.

Comment: Because you are iterating over the underlying list, i.e. `for i in msg.stack:` but the list size is changing in your for-loop, leading to the behavior you are seeing (skipping elements)

Comment: Instead, you could use a while loop to do this simply: `while msg.size: msg.pop()` or take care while you are iterating (always messy if you are mutating the container you are iterating over)

Comment: Seems like more of a caveat to watch out for than anything else. `i` doesn't follow the rules I thought it would within my loops. At least I understand now, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is fundamentally that you are iterating over a container while you modify it. Think about it this way, internally, a `list` iterator simply keeps advancing an index until it hits an `IndexError`. Since you *modify* the list, it hits the `IndexError` after you've removed 3 elemnts from it, because it will try `my_list[3]` but `len(my_list) == 3`. There are several ways around this. The first, just use a while-loop in this case:

```
In [4]: class Stack:
   ...:
   ...:     def __init__(self, data):
   ...:         self.stack = [i for i in data]
   ...:         self.size = int(len(self.stack))
   ...:
   ...:     def pop(self):
   ...:         ch = self.stack[self.size - 1]
   ...:         del(self.stack[-1])
   ...:         self.size = self.size - 1
   ...:         return ch
   ...:     def __len__(self):
   ...:         return self.size
   ...:

In [5]: stack = Stack("Hello!")

In [6]: while stack:
   ...:     print(stack.pop(), end='')
   ...:
!olleH
```

Note, I defined a `__len__` method so that `while stack:` works directly instead of `while stack.size:`

You can also, as you figured out, simply loop over a range object instead:

```
In [7]: stack = Stack("Hello!")

In [8]: for _ in range(len(stack)):
   ...:     print(stack.pop(), end='')
   ...:
!olleH
```

More tricky: loop in the *reverse* direction! Since you pop from the end, you won't get an `IndexError`, because a `list_reverseiterator` starts indexing at `alist[len(alist) - 1]` until it gets to `alist[0]`. I probably wouldn't feel comfortable relying ont this behavior, but it is documented, and it does work:

```
In [9]: stack = Stack("Hello!")

In [10]: for _ in reversed(stack.stack):
    ...:     print(stack.pop(), end='')
    ...:
!olleH
In [11]:
```

Finally, the tried and true: loop over a *copy*:

```
In [11]: stack = Stack("Hello!")

In [12]: for _ in stack.stack[:]: #whole slice copies
    ...:     print(stack.pop(), end='')
    ...:
!olleH
```

Comment: What a deeply perceptive answer! +1 (if I could) and Thank you. This question actually came about while I was creating different reverse iterators. I have much to learn yet about Python's magic methods.

Comment: If I may add; you said that the list continues to iterate until it reaches IndexError. Is that analogous if not identical to saying `raise StopIteration`

Comment: @Mostly_Yoshi The problem is that there are actually *two* iterator protocols, one involving `__next__` and `StopIteration` the other (used by built-in sequences like `list` and `str`) involve `__getitem__` and `IndexError`, although this is remains mostly to not break old code, but they work analogously